# heirloom-mailx sending emails to extra recipients

Tags: email, mailx

One of my clients just moved from one host to another. I copied his cron and set up it.

The `cron` runs a `mysqldump` and then emails the file to the client. The script only has 1 email address specified. For some reason, the generated email include 6 addresses total. The specified address is 5th in the list. The addresses are all of the host, not the client.

They range from `backup@host.com`, `-s@host.com`, `database@host.com`, `IT@host.com`, and `clientname@host.com` and `clientname@clientdomain.com`.

```
echo 'Your MySQL Backup is attached' | mail -a $MYFILEPATH/$DBNAME-backup-$DATE.sql.gz $EMAIL2 -s "MySQL database backup"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved.  Whatever was running on the old server allowed the subject to come after the email address.  The new server does not and was treating the subject as email accounts on the host.